# Convert "datetime.date(2019, 3, 21)" to "2019/03/21"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, datetime, nested-lists

I have a list of lists which looks like:

```
[['2019-001', datetime.date(2019, 3, 21), 'Services']]
```

I would like the result to look like this:

```
[['2019-001', '2019/03/21', 'Services']]
```

I will need to iterate over the entire list of lists as I don't know where all of those datetime entries are located.  Should I use regex, or is there a better/faster/more Pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following, using a list-comp and [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)? If you don't know which element in your list is going to be the `datetime` object, the best we can do is by checking every element.

```
>>> l = [['2019-001', datetime.date(2019, 3, 21), 'Services']]
>>> [[x.strftime('%Y/%m/%d') if isinstance(x, datetime.date) else x for x in sl] for sl in l]
[['2019-001', '2019/03/21', 'Services']]
```

Comment: @AlanW. Basically, in the outer list, we have ‘for sl in l’. This is my shorthand for ‘for sublist in list’. So for every sublist in the initial list, we want our new list to have a sublist. In each of those sublists, we want to check if each element is a date object, and if so, convert it using strftime. Otherwise, we just keep it as it is. Hope that helps a little!